# Как не открывать всплывающее окно при условии, что

Tags: javascript, jquery, форма, условия

Как не открывать всплывающее окно при условии, что файл в поле `input type="file"` не прикреплен?

Пробовал делать так но не работает

```
if(file.val()) {
  $('.contenth__bottom_btns').magnificPopup({
    type:"inline",
    mainClass: 'mfp-forms'
  });

} else {
  $('.contenth__bottom_btns').attr({
    'href' : ''
  });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if($('input.file')[0].files.length > 0) { 
    $('.contenth__bottom_btns').magnificPopup({
        type:"inline",
        mainClass: 'mfp-forms'
    });

  } else {
   $('.contenth__bottom_btns').attr({
   'href' : ''
  });

  }
```

Comment: К сожалению не работает, все равно идет запрос на открытие всплывающей формы, можно с вами как-то в скайпе связаться?

Comment: @LiEm скайп alucid2